# The way to optimize react and Typescript codes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

In this case, I used React + TypeScript and ant-design. The following code works perfectly but I want the codes to be summarized as much as possible. This is about starting a site that has 3 pages. For example, how can I write this part (`const { id, title, description, background } = splash;`) so that I don't need to define (`splashs[index].background , splashs[index].title, splashs[index].description`) all the time.
Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```css
.splash {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
  background-color: var(--cjp);
}

.BgGradiant {
  background: linear-gradient(107.78deg, rgba(80, 21, 100, 0) 1.87%, rgba(80, 21, 100, 0.05) 18.6%, rgba(80, 21, 100, 0.51) 25.79%, #1C3396 99.02%, #1C3396 51.08%);

}

.context{
  width: 80%;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.content h1,
.content p {
  color: var(--cwh);
}

.backgroundImage>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btns {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-margin-start: auto;
  margin-inline-start: auto;
  -webkit-margin-end: auto;
  margin-inline-end: auto;
  -webkit-margin-before: 2rem;
  margin-block-start: 7rem;
}


.btns :global(.ant-btn){
  background-color: var(--cwh);
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius12);
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 10px !important;
}

.btns :global(.ant-btn)::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 125%;
  height: 125%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid var(--chb);
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius14);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btns :global(.ant-btn > span){
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.btns :global(.ant-btn > span > svg){
  fill: var(--cal);
}

.btnSkip {
  background-color: unset;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: var(--cca);
}

.btnLogin{
  -webkit-margin-before: 2rem;
  margin-block-start: 7rem;
}

.btnLogin :global(.ant-btn){
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius10);
  background-color: var(--cwh);
  color: var(--cjp);
}

.btnLogin :global(.ant-btn > span){
  font-family: "Display-Bold";
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dotActive {
  background-color: var(--cwh);
}

.dotDeActive {
  background-color: var(--cca);
}

.dot:not(:last-child) {
  -webkit-margin-end: 0.5rem;
  margin-inline-end: 0.5rem;
}

.contentInner{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-padding-before: 2rem;
  padding-block-start: 2rem;
  -webkit-padding-after: 3rem;
  padding-block-end: 3rem;
}

.contentInner1{
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contentInner2{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'antd';
import { ArrowRightOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import Container from '../../Components/UI/Container/Container'
import classes from './Splash.module.css';
import { backgroundSplash1, backgroundSplash2, logoImage } from '../../Assets/index';


const Splash = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

    const {
        splash,
        bg,
        BgGradiant,
        context,
        content,
        backgroundImage,
        logo,
        btns,
        btnLogin,
        btnSkip,
        dots,
        dot,
        dotActive,
        dotDeActive,
        contentInner,
        contentInner1,
        contentInner2,
    } = classes

    const splashs = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'Page 1 : title 1',
            desctiption: '1- Lorem ipsum 1 ',
            background: logoImage,
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Page 2 : title 2',
            desctiption: '2- Lorem ipsum 2 ',
            background: backgroundSplash1,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Page 3 : title3',
            desctiption: '3- Lorem ipsum 3',
            background: backgroundSplash2,
        }
    ];

    const nextBnt = () => {
        setIndex(index + 1);
        if (index === splashs.length - 1) {
            return navigate("/login");
        }
    }

    const skipBtn = () => {
        console.log('skip ');
        return navigate("/login");
    }

    const loginBtn = () => {
        return navigate("/login");
    }



    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={24}>
                    <section
                        className={`${index === 0 ? bg : BgGradiant} ${splash}`}>
                        {
                            splashs.map((splash) => {
                                const { id, title, desctiption, background } = splash;
                                console.log(title, "title");

                                return (
                                    <>

                                        {
                                            index !== 0 && (
                                                <div className={backgroundImage}>
                                                    <img src={splashs[index].background} />
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        }


                                        <Container key={id} className={backgroundImage}>
                                            <div className={`${index === 0 ? contentInner1 : contentInner2} ${contentInner}`}>
                                                {
                                                    index === 0 && (
                                                        <div className={logo}>
                                                            <img src={logoImage} alt="logoImage" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    )
                                                }

                                                <div className={context}>
                                                    <div className={content}>
                                                        <h1>{splashs[index].title}</h1>
                                                        <p>{splashs[index].desctiption}</p>
                                                    </div>

                                                    {/* BTNS */}
                                                    {
                                                        index === splashs.length - 1 ? (
                                                            <div className={btnLogin}>
                                                                <Button block onClick={loginBtn}>Login</Button>
                                                            </div>

                                                        ) : (
                                                            <div className={btns}>
                                                                <button className={btnSkip} onClick={skipBtn}>skip</button>
                                                                <Button onClick={nextBnt}> <ArrowRightOutlined /></Button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Container>
                                    </>
                                )
                            })
                        }


                        <div className={dots}>
                            {
                                Array.from({ length: 3 }).map((item, idx) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={idx} className={`${dot} ${index === idx ? dotActive : dotDeActive}`}></div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default Splash;
```

Comment: Rather than a code dump of your entire setup including completely irrelevant CSS, please post a *minimal, complete* reproduction case and state your question clearly. Your title and the body of your question seem completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice, your question isn't really well formulated so it's hard to understand what are you trying to accomplish. Try to keep the questions clear and remove any redundant code so the community can better understand it.

If I'm assuming correctly that you don't want to use `splash[index]` then you should change `splash[index].title` to `title`, same for the other props.

Since you already destructured the splash object with `const { id, title, description, background } = splash;` all these will be available.

Another thing here is, `.map` method returns the item in the array so I don't see the point in you using the index inside the loop to access the item from the array.